# Identity Management for Enterprise Apps, OpenId, Gmail, etc

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, federation

I am new to identity management, is there a management tool that can be used to manage:

1. Enterprise Applications
2. Gmail
3. SAAS
4. OpenId
5. LDAP
6. Etc.

The idea is to have a single point to create a user inside the management tool (stored on ldap or database), and within the same management tool, we can automatically create accounts for this user to other applications stated above.

what i dug so far is CAS, SSO, i don't know where to start looking

Answer (score 0):

There are many flavors of these solutions.  "Creating accounts" (or updating / removing them) is typically referred to as "user provisioning", and is a common feature of Identity Managemenet Systems.  Other features include central auditing, single sign-on/authentication and authorization capabilities.

- Traditional Identity Management solutions (focused primarily on Enterprise applications) that are on the "heavy-weight" side of things.  Some of the leaders [are summarized here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_systems#List_of_Leading_Identity_management_systems).
- Cloud (or SaaS) focused solutions, [such as Ping Identity](https://www.pingidentity.com/) (full disclosure - I work for Ping).  These solutions are typically lighter-weight and more adept into providing seamless integration with applications such as Google Apps (Gmail), Salesforce, etc.  It comes with adapters that enable integration with LDAP and RDBMS systems, and implements open standards including OpenID, SAML, OAuth, etc.

Comment: Thanks, will look into Ping Identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have look at [WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) which is free and open source. It supports Single Sign On via OpenID, SAML2 and implements a flexible user store via built-in LDAP. Also it can be configured to use custom user stores.